# I am writting an mvc application and having an error when trying to get a loop of products using strongly-typed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I created a strongly typed view which view data class is the class called ProductList. I am returning to the view a list object as well that comes from getting all  the products by using linq to entitites. Why am I getting an error when trying to use the product.name as shown on the code below on the view. Im very new on this so sorry if my question is bad. Any help would be very appreciated

```
public class ProductList
{
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

this is the controller :

```
  public ViewResult List()
    {
       IQueryable<Product> allproducts= productrepository.selectAll();

        return View(allproducts.ToList());
    }
```

and this is the view :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TradeIt.Models.ProductListViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
List
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<% foreach (var product in Model.Products)
   { %>

   <%: Html.LabelFor(product.Name) %>

<% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

**I am getting the next error: The type argument for method 'system.web.mvc.html.labelExtensions.LabelFor... cannot be inferred from the usage . Try specifiying the type arguments explicitly'**

Comment: `Html.LabelFor(x => product.Name)` Is probably what you mean.

Comment: I made the change thanks for the answer but now im getting the runtime error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TradeIt.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TradeIt.Models.ProductListViewModel'

Answer (score 0):

change this

"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

your model is called ProductList, not ProductListViewModel

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it is called ProductListViewModel

Comment: what if you change IQueryable<Product> to IQueryable<ProductListViewModel>?